# How does in ThreadPoolExecutor implemented that submit method swallow exception, but execute -not

Tags: java, concurrency, exception, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

As is known ThreadPoolExecutor have 2 methods to push tasks:

submit and execute.

As I understand - main difference the following:

Submit returns `Future` and if we can observe exeption occured in task after call

```
future.get();
```

But if exception occures in task pushed as submit - we will see this exception in console(surely if this exception will not explicitly catch)

I tried to investigate `ThreadPoolExecutor` code and find how this was implemented.

The thing I noticed, `submit` method uses `execute` method inside:

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

But I cannot find place in code where detects should we swallow exception - or not.

Please help to find this logic in code.

Comment: Actually, this has been said already in the second paragraph of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42423289/2711488) to an older question from you…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `task`is a a `FutureTask`.

If you look at the source code ([grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#FutureTask)) of the `run` method :

```
try {
    result = c.call();
    ran = true;
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    result = null;
    ran = false;
    setException(ex);
}
```

You see that all `Throwable` are swallowed here.

Comment: hmm logic inside FutureTask class. Thus if I create FutureTask and invoke execute method - exception will not shown explicitly too